# Only return if main query has all the rows that subquery returns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query that would return data if and only if it has all the `ids` that the subquery would return

What I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM sub_table WHERE SOMECODITION)
```

but it returns once it finds at least one matching row in sub query which i do not want.

Mainly I wanna be able to check if the `main_table` has all the `ids` that `sub_table` returns

EDIT:

the `SOMECONDITION` has nothing to do with main query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather painful in MySQL.  The following gets the number of matches:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM main_table
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM sub_table WHERE SOMECODITION);
```

If you only want to select the rows, I would suggest that you get the count in php and use conditional logic there.  But, you can also do that in SQL:

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM main_table mt
WHERE mt.id IN ( SELECT st.id FROM sub_table st WHERE SOMECONDITION) AND
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT mt.id)
       FROM main_table mt
       WHERE mt.id IN (SELECT st.id FROM sub_table st WHERE SOMECONDITION)
      ) =
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT st.id) FROM sub_table st WHERE SOMECONDITION);
```

Comment: I think if the `sub_table` has more rows that satisfies the `SOMECONDITION` then your solution wouldn't work.

Comment: @Sam . . . I don't follow your comment.  This should be matching distinct counts between the two tables.

Comment: Check the example I gave in my answer and see if your solution works for that.

Comment: @Sam . . . I don't see how it applies.  `NULL` values are not going to ever match the `IN` condition and this answer does not use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using `left join` as well. Like for instance, let's take a small example `main_table` has ids `1,2,3` and `sub_table` has ids `1,2,5,6` (that matches `SOMECONDITION`) so the following query,

```
select s.id sid,m.id mid from 
sub_table s left join main_table m on s.id = m.id where s.SOMECONDITION
```

would result in:

```
sid     mid
1       1
2       2
5       null
6       null
```

In this case main table does not have all the IDs that the sub query returns. 
You can make use of `count` to fetch results only if the `count(sid)` equals `count(mid)`, since `count` doesn't consider `null` values. So your query would become.

```
SELECT * FROM main_table 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM sub_table WHERE SOMECODITION)
AND
(select count(Distinct sid) 
from (select s.id sid,m.id mid from sub_table s left join main_table m on 
s.id = m.id where s.SOMECONDITION) )
= (select count(Distinct mid) 
from (select s.id sid,m.id mid from sub_table s left join main_table m on 
s.id = m.id where s.SOMECONDITION) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `inner join` in this case.

```
SELECT m.* FROM main_table INNER JOIN sub_table s ON m.id = s.id WHERE SOMECODITION
```

I assume the `SOMECODITION` contains only conditions against `sub_table`. With `SOMECODITION`, it's guaranteed that the result from `sub_table` must meet the condition and with `INNER JOIN`, all id's from `sub_table` must be found in `main_table` in order to return something from `main_table`.